# Javascript error when trying to call a function and an if else statement with keypress

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the location of the red circles based on key presses where I call the functions, but I get an error and I am a beginner so I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I want those red circles to disappear after a while, thats why I put the timeout code and I want them to be appearing over an image.

Can anyone please help? I am sure this is a 2 minute fix but I am just not good at coding.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-image: url("violin.jpg");
        background-size: 2500px 1300px;
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
      } 
  </head>
  </style>
  <img id="bow" src="bow.jpg" style="display:none;" />
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener("keydown", soundPlay);
    function fillRed() {
      ctx.fillStyle = "red,";
      ctx.fill();
    }
    function keyQ() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(500, 500, 30,0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fill();
    }
    function keyW() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(300, 300, 40,0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fill();
    }
    function keyE() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(900, 500, 20,0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fill();
    }
    function keyR() {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(950, 100, 20,0, Math.PI*2);
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
      ctx.fill();
    }
    ///var x = event.keyCode;
    <input type="text" onkeydown="pressedKey(event)">

    **THE ERROR I AM HAVING IS HERE**

    function pressedKey(event) {
      var x = event.keyCode;
      if (x == 27) { // 27 is the ESC key
        alert ("You pressed the Escape key!");
      } else if (x == 81) {
        keyQ();   
        var sound = new Audio('1.mp3');
        sound.play();
        setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
      } else if (event.keyCode == 87) {
        keyW();
        var sound = new Audio("2.mp3");
        sound.play();
        setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
      } else if (event.keyCode == 69) {
        keyE();
        var sound = new Audio("3.mp3");
        sound.play();
        setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
      } else if (event.keyCode == 82) {
        keyR();
        var sound = new Audio("4.mp3");
        sound.play();
        setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
      }
    }
  </script>
}
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Demis,

You have a few things incorrect with this code :

1. You have HTML in your styles... (canvas)
2. You have HTML hanging around in your script (input)
3. You have closing curly braces outside of your script (which wont error in html but i can just see that it should be either gone or INSIDE your script tag)
4. Your head and style tags aren't nested properly. you are closing your head before closing your style.

Cheers

Comment: thanks man so you are saying the reason for the error is the following :<input type="text" onkeydown="pressedKey(event)">
i only get an error where the functions are

Comment: What i am saying is, fundamentally theres a few things incorrect with your code. 

If you are going to reference HTML within a script tag then it has to be as a string i.e: "<input />"

start by taking any HTML tags that are inside your script tag and moving them inside the <body>...</body>

see if that helps. 

Also just an FYI - when getting errors in the console. its good to copy give us reference to the error in your original question.

Comment: Thanks alot you are a savior i followed the steps you provided and i am not getting any errors also the code looks alot more neat but the red circles are still not appearing

Comment: That's OK. Not only is it neater but, it is also correct ;-)

Regarding the circles... that's for you to debug and figure out :-)

Comment: Also : Google "switch JS statements".

Answer (score 0):

## Here's the same code with fixes and comments

There were severe errors in the markup suggesting (as you admit) that you're in need of basic tuition.

It's great that you're giving web development a try, and we all had to start somewhere, but my advice is that you learn to walk before trying to run.

I recommend taking [a gentle walkthrough course at w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) to learn the basics of how to build web pages, before concerning yourself with what you're going to fill them.

When you have a good understanding of how to construct web pages, then you can move on to more complex coding and [more thorough documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web).

---

Some parts of the code below are commented out because they simply won't work embedded in this website, but they may work in your own development environment (as long as the required resources exist where they should).

You may notice that I moved the `<script>` to below the `<canvas>` so that the `<canvas>` already exists before the JavaScript tries to use it.
You can learn a bit more about this issue by reading the examples given in [the MDN documentation about `document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState).
There are other ways to detect the readiness of the DOM before trying to use it, which would allow that the `<script>` can remain in the `<head>`, but for simplicity and brevity, I opted to simply move it.

As for your `fillRed()` function, if the idea is for

> ... those red circles to disappear after a while, thats why I put the timeout code ...

that code is a long way short of doing what you're hoping.
MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) has [an indepth `<canvas>` tutorial on their site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) that will help you understand the basics, and some more advanced stuff.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
      body {
        /*background-image: url("violin.jpg"); file not available on SO*/
        background-size: 2500px 1300px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="768"></canvas>
    <!-- <img id="bow" src="bow.jpg" style="display:none;"> not displayed -->
    <input type="text" onkeydown="pressedKey(event)">
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      //window.addEventListener("keydown", soundPlay); // soundPlay is not defined
      function fillRed() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // this will not make the circle disappear
        ctx.fill();
      }
      function keyQ() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(500, 500, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
      }
      function keyW() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(300, 300, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
      }
      function keyE() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(900, 500, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
      }
      function keyR() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(950, 100, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();
      }
      function pressedKey(event) {
        var x = event.keyCode;
        if (x == 27) { // 27 is the ESC key
          alert("You pressed the Escape key!");
        } else if (x == 81) {
          keyQ();
          //var sound = new Audio('1.mp3'); // requires file not available on SO
          //sound.play();
          setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
        } else if (event.keyCode == 87) {
          keyW();
          //var sound = new Audio("2.mp3"); // requires file not available on SO
          //sound.play();
          setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
        } else if (event.keyCode == 69) {
          keyE();
          //var sound = new Audio("3.mp3"); // requires file not available on SO
          //sound.play();
          setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
        } else if (event.keyCode == 82) {
          keyR();
          //var sound = new Audio("4.mp3"); // requires file not available on SO
          //sound.play();
          setTimeout(fillRed, 200);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and putting in the work to do this. I have the audio and image files saved on my computer and those are showing just fine. You made me notice that i forgot to call my function "soundplay" and that is why it was not able to run. As i said i am new to this and will have a look at the links you have provided

Comment: I assumed you'd have the necessary files on your system; I'm glad you understand why they're commented out here. I'm also pleased to hear you'll read the linked documentation; coding has been, for me, some of the best fun I've ever had, and on occasions more frustrating than I thought I could stand - it is challenging and rewarding. Keep learning and trying new things, but to save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run, start simple and work up :-)